# Running two loops simultaneously in bash

Tags: bash

I am reading file in which two different types of key-value pairs are there and I have to pass those key-value pairs to another file. For that I have to run two loops which doesn't seems me the optimized approach. Below the code I am trying and it will also clarify you what I am trying to do :

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# Prints command usage
function usage() {
  cat <<EOF

Usage: $0 [--in-file <infile>] [--env <env>]

EOF
}
env=""
# Parse Args
POSITIONAL=()
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  key="$1"

  case $key in
  -i|--in-file)
    in_file=$2
    shift 2 # past argument and value
    ;;
  -e|--env)
    env="$2"
    shift 2 # past argument and value
    ;;
  *) # unknown option
    echo "unknown option"
    shift # past argument
    ;;
  esac
done
set -- "${POSITIONAL[@]}" # restore positional parameters

if [[ ${in_file} == "" ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: Missing in-file argument"
  usage
  exit 1
fi

cat ${in_file}

echo "Unsilencing alarms"
declare -A summary
overall_status_failed="false"
silence_ids=`yq read -j ${in_file} alarm_ids | jq -M -r .[]`
while read -r silence_id; do
  echo "Unsilencing ${silence_id} silence id"
  if [env != ""]; then 
    ./unsilence_alarm.sh --alarm-id ${silence_id} --env ${env}|| script_failed="true"
  else 
    ./unsilence_alarm.sh --alarm-id ${silence_id}|| script_failed="true"
  fi
  if [[ "${script_failed}" == "true" ]]; then
    summary["silence id ${silence_id}      "]='Fail'
    overall_status_failed="true"
    script_failed="false"
  else
    summary["silence id ${silence_id}      "]='Pass'
  fi
done <<< "${silence_ids}"

echo "Unsilencing moody alarms"
silence_ids=`yq read -j ${in_file} moody_alarm_ids | jq -M -r .[]`
while read -r silence_id; do
  echo "Unsilencing ${silence_id} moody silence id"
  if [env != ""]; then
    ./unsilence_alarm.sh --moody-alarm-id ${silence_id} --env ${env}|| script_failed="true"
  else 
    ./unsilence_alarm.sh --moody-alarm-id ${silence_id}|| script_failed="true"
  fi
  if [[ "${script_failed}" == "true" ]]; then
    summary["moody silence id ${silence_id}"]="Fail"
    overall_status_failed="true"
    script_failed="false"
  else
    summary["moody silence id ${silence_id}"]="Pass"
  fi
done <<< "${silence_ids}"

set +x
echo
echo
echo
echo +------------------------- Unsilence summary --------------------------+
for status in "${!summary[@]}"; do
  printf "${status} - ${summary[$status]}\n"
done
echo +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
if [[ "${overall_status_failed}" == "true" ]]; then
  exit 1
fi
exit
```

Can anyone tell me the optimized approach for merging these two while loops? Another file accepts the parameters like:

```
[--alarm-id <id>] [--moody-alarm-id <id>] [--env <env>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine both `while` blocks with the help of [associative arrays](https://opensource.com/article/20/6/associative-arrays-bash) and wrap it in `for`

Does this work as expected?

```
...

declare -A flags
flags[alarm_ids]="--alarm-id"
flags[moody_alarm_ids]="--moody-alarm-id"

for alarm_id in alarm_ids moody_alarm_ids; do
    silence_ids=`yq read -j ${in_file} ${alarm_id} | jq -M -r .[]`
    
    while read -r silence_id; do
        echo "Unsilencing ${silence_id} silence id"
      
        ./unsilence_alarm.sh ${flags[$alarm_id]} ${silence_id} ${env:+"--env ${env}"} \
            || script_failed="true"

    if [[ "${script_failed}" == "true" ]]; then
        summary["silence ${flag[alarm_id]//-/ } ${silence_id}      "]='Fail'
        overall_status_failed="true"
        script_failed="false"
    else
        summary["silence ${flag[alarm_id]//-/ } ${silence_id}      "]='Pass'
    fi

    done <<< "${silence_ids}"
done
...
```

**Simultaneous** would not be easy. If you do need it, wrap the above code snippet in a function **without** the `for` loop; and use a parameter to pass the "key" to the the while loop. And then you could start them as background activities with `foo &`. But that would not make it easier for summary. Since you need to `wait` for it to complete anyway - synchronous is the way to go.

Also `${env:+"--env ${env}"}` expands to the rhs of `+` if lhs (`env`) is not null. Using 4-statement long `if-else` block seemed tedious. I am not sure if this method is frowned upon, but this is how I personally would have done it.

Comment: When I do echo for ${env:+"--env ${env}"} I am getting --env value, but when I execute it with ./unsilence_alarm.sh --alarm-id ${silence_id} ${env:+"--env ${env}"}|| script_failed="true" I am not getting any value in unsilence_alarm.sh

Comment: i don't seem to be having that problem. try running the entire script with `-x`. (passing a smaller sample set as in-file will make it easier to analyse the output)

Comment: ps: made an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67734612/revisions) to the if-else block for assigning values to `summary` to kindof match the original output.